# Placing an adorner on a datatemplate in XAML only?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following DataTemplate :

```
<DataTemplate>

<Grid>
<1-- Content -->
</Grid>

</DataTempalte>
```

I want to place an adorner on top of the content of the Grid.

How can I do that?

The adorner I want to use is another Grid.

Can we do this in pure XAML only?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I have made very good experience with the following code:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/54472/Defining-WPF-Adorners-in-XAML

After adding some classes to your code base you are able to define Adorners in Xaml like so:

```
<local:AdornedControl x:Name="adornedControl" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
    HorizontalAdornerPlacement="Outside" VerticalAdornerPlacement="Outside" IsAdornerVisible="True"
        IsMouseOverShowEnabled="False">
<local:AdornedControl.AdornerContent>
    <Canvas x:Name="adornerCanvas" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Thumb Canvas.Top="-5" Canvas.Left="-5" />
        <Thumb Canvas.Bottom="-5" Canvas.Left="-5" />
        <Thumb Canvas.Top="-5" Canvas.Right="-5" />
        <Thumb Canvas.Bottom="-5" Canvas.Right="-5" />
    </Canvas>
</local:AdornedControl.AdornerContent>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, WPF Adorners must be implemented in code as you'll see on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746703.aspx).

If you can't create an Andorner in code, you might consider just layering the XAML you wanted in the DataTemplate directly. Additionally, as Adorners use [DrawingContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.aspx) for rendering, you'll find using a Grid won't be practical either.

Comment: Do you mean that if a grid's dimensions are undefined using a DrawingContext will not work as it needs coordinates to work with, right ?